# Want a dual-boot menu at each start-up

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12. 04 in a separate partition in a pre-installed Windows 7 laptop.

Initially when I start up the machine it gives me a menu to choose between two OSs.Then after updating Ubuntu system by default boots to Ubuntu. So I posted a question here with the  help of one response now I get the default boot to windows7.

But I want boot menu at each startup to choose between Windows and Ubuntu. I have tried easyBCD. After adding an entry in easybcd a boot menu appears in startup.But when I choose Ubuntu after a black screen the purple screen of Ubuntu comes for 2-3seconds and then Windows is booted.

Comment: Needs confirmation: are you using wubi installation? What change did you made? (at least point us to the instruction you followed)

Comment: No, i have not used wubi installation.I  installed ubuntu in a separate partition.

Comment: How want want to choose ubuntu - windows? via windows bootloader or grub. Grub is much easier to setup

Comment: Since i can boot to my windows os i think windows bootloader is my option.

Comment: I think I know what's wrong but am unsure of how to explain a fix I think that grub-timeout=0 may have been added (just a guess)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Windows DVD? Enter the DVD, click on Repair, then click repair boot. It should add Windows 7 (but the Ubuntu system will be removed).

Boot to Windows and use [Easy BCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/).

The non-commercial version is enough. After installing choose Ubuntu and other relevant settings and you will be done.

Comment: I can boot into Windows.In easybcd i follow these steps: Add new entry>Linux/BSD>Type GRUB2>Add entry>BCD deployment>Install the windows7 loader>Write MBR. But that doesn't help.